# Redis + Elasticsearch - Will it work?

Tags: caching, elasticsearch, redis, api-design

As a new programmer, I'm currently working on a personal project and had some troubles with the design of my application.

Let's imagine I've got a database(PostgreSQL) with thousands of articles. I shall store them into my Elasticsearch index, to make a quick search through my **list** of articles. I also want to implement a caching system in the logic, and so I shall store the detail of each article in Redis.

So, I plan to use Elasticsearch to retrieve the list, and Redis to cache the detail of each article.

My questions are :

1 - Is there something wrong with the use case utilization of both Redis and Elasticsearch? Do I really need both to do what I want or is it "*overkill*"?

2 - If I store the details in Redis and the list in Elasticsearch, does that mean I will never have to request my API to get the data that I want to display?

Comment: It sounds okay, but if you just want to go with redis try http://redisearch.io/

Comment: I don't think there is enough information to give an answer — for example what does "quick search through my list of articles" mean specifically? Generally I'd start without caching and only add it if it's necessary (premature optimization and everything)